# Is there a shorter way to do this by mod,i want to make every other letter of a word capital.To MaKe It LiKe ThIs

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a shorter way to do this by mod,i want to make every other letter of a word capital.To MaKe It LiKe ThIs.

```
 x = input("enter word=")
    if x[2].islower():
        x = x[:2] + x[2].upper() + x[3:]
    if x[4].islower():
        x = x[:4] + x[4].upper() + x[5:]
    if x[6].islower():
        x = x[:6] + x[6].upper() + x[7:]
    if x[8].islower():
        x = x[:8] + x[8].upper() + x[9:]
    if x[10].islower():
        x = x[:10] + x[10].upper() + x[10:]            
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach using python's inbuilt `textwrap`

```
from textwrap import wrap
s = 'abcdefghijk'
s = "".join([ele.title() for ele in wrap(s, 2)])
```

**Output**

```
'AbCdEfGhIjK'
```

Comment: This code is doing weird stuff
`
from textwrap import wrap
s ="Money"
s = s.join([ele.title() for ele in wrap(s, 2)])

print(s)
`
Output:
`
MoMoneyNeMoneyY  
`

Comment: sorry what do you mean by weird stuff do you have a sample output i can try?

Comment: I type "Money" in s and the ouput is:MoMoneyNeMoneyY

Comment: Ahh. saw your code you are doing `s.join` instead of `"".join` the later is basically `str.join`

Answer (score 4):

You can use list slices to modify your string:

```
x = list(x)
x[::2] = map(str.upper, x[::2])
x = ''.join(x)
```

Or use a generator with `enumerate`:

```
x = ''.join(c if i%2 else c.upper() for i, c in enumerate(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a for loop:

```
for y in range(2,11,2):
  if x[y].islower():
    x = x[:y] + x[y].upper() + x[y+1:]

print(x)
```